# I want to delete the line in a file which matches the exact pattern not the string

Tags: shell, sed

I want to delete the line in a file which matches the exact pattern not the string i have key value property if i type only the key it should not delete the property it should ask me for exact match or give me a message no match found only when it matches exactly it should delete the line.

```
sed -i '/nodeName:/d' etc/dir.txt
```

This deletes the line that start  with the nodeName: but i want to keep this and delete only when i give nodeName  = xyz.

```
sed -i "/nodeName:/d" etc/dir.txt
```

The file will look like:

```
  nodeName: 'HKLGIDWAS11_HK_DMGR01'
  dmgrPath: '/IBM/websphere/DMGR_SAN/profiles/DEV_WAAS_CRBKG01_HK_DMGR01'
  clusterName: 'DEV_WAAS_eBBSONL_MY_DC'
```

in the command if i give only the nodename: it should give me no match found message if i enter `nodeName: 'HKLGIDWAS11_HK_DMGR01'` it should delete the property and give me a message property deleted

Comment: You mix code and explanation, without any code flag, it's hardly readable ans understandable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if grep -q -x "$1" etc/dir.txt; then
   sed -i "/$1/d" etc/dir.txt
   echo $1 deleted 
else
   echo " No match found"
fi
```

**Example**

File name of given text: `t2.txt`

Script: `ta1.sh`

```
cat t2.txt
nodeName: 'HKLGIDWAS11_HK_DMGR01'
dmgrPath: '/IBM/websphere/DMGR_SAN/profiles/DEV_WAAS_CRBKG01_HK_DMGR01'
clusterName: 'DEV_WAAS_eBBSONL_MY_DC'

./ta1.sh nodeName:
 No match found

cat t2.txt
nodeName: 'HKLGIDWAS11_HK_DMGR01'
dmgrPath: '/IBM/websphere/DMGR_SAN/profiles/DEV_WAAS_CRBKG01_HK_DMGR01'
clusterName: 'DEV_WAAS_eBBSONL_MY_DC'

./ta1.sh "nodeName: 'HKLGIDWAS11_HK_DMGR01'"
nodeName: 'HKLGIDWAS11_HK_DMGR01' deleted

cat t2.txt
dmgrPath: '/IBM/websphere/DMGR_SAN/profiles/DEV_WAAS_CRBKG01_HK_DMGR01'
clusterName: 'DEV_WAAS_eBBSONL_MY_DC'
```